# Display PDF images in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, pdf, images

*Note: This question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15407485/491532) before, with no success.*

Org-mode’s ability to display inline images is fantastic for writing
my weekly scientific reports. I can include graphs, link them with
their data, link with the conclusions, and really harness the power of
org-mode.

The only problem I have is that org needs the images to use
conventional image formats (jpeg, png, etc), while I prefer for my
graphs to be in PDF.

**How can I display inline pdf images in org-mode?**

My final objective is to just write a link like this in org-mode:

```
[[file:~/Work/grap.pdf]]
```

And have it displayed inline just like it would happen if it were a png.

*I know I could just have a copy of each graph in jpeg or something
(which is what I do right now), but it’s slightly cumbersome and it
always carries the risk of the pdf graph being updated and me
forgetting to update the jpeg.*

Comment: This might work as a solution: Going along the lines of `endless/update-includes`, if during `before-save-hook`, if you find a line with `#+NAME` or `#+CAPTION` with a tag like `:convertfrompdf` followed by a line with `[[SOMEFILE.EXT]]`, then you execute the Imagemagick `convert` function to convert `SOMEFILE.pdf` to `SOMEFILE.EXT`.

Comment: @kaushalmodi yeah. another option would be something that hooks into org-display-images.

Comment: A solution based on pdf-tools/poppler would be nice.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**NOTE**: You need to have ImageMagick installed on your system (`convert` executable) for this solution to work.

## How this solution is implemented

- The function `org-include-img-from-pdf` is the workhorse that does the PDF to Image format conversion using `convert`.
- If the org file contains `# ()convertfrompdf:t`, it will be assumed that the user has a pdf file that they want to convert to an image file. The user should put the above *special comment* above the image file link as shown in the below example.
- The image file type is determined by the file extension in the bracket link `[[./myimage.EXT]]`.
- By adding the `org-include-img-from-pdf` function to the `before-save-hook`, that function is executed every time the user saves the file (See the elisp snippet following the function definition below).

## Example setup

In this example setup I have the following files:

- An org file like below that includes an image file.
- The pdf file `myimage.pdf`.

```org
# ()convertfrompdf:t
[[./myimage.png]]
```

## Function to auto convert pdf to image files

```el
(defun org-include-img-from-pdf (&rest _)
  "Convert pdf files to image files in org-mode bracket links.

    # ()convertfrompdf:t # This is a special comment; tells that the upcoming
                         # link points to the to-be-converted-to file.
    # If you have a foo.pdf that you need to convert to foo.png, use the
    # foo.png file name in the link.
    [[./foo.png]]
"
  (interactive)
  (if (executable-find "convert")
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (while (re-search-forward "^[ \t]*#\\s-+()convertfrompdf\\s-*:\\s-*t"
                                  nil :noerror)
          ;; Keep on going to the next line till it finds a line with bracketed
          ;; file link.
          (while (progn
                   (forward-line 1)
                   (not (looking-at org-bracket-link-regexp))))
          ;; Get the sub-group 1 match, the link, from `org-bracket-link-regexp'
          (let ((link (match-string-no-properties 1)))
            (when (stringp link)
              (let* ((imgfile (expand-file-name link))
                     (pdffile (expand-file-name
                               (concat (file-name-sans-extension imgfile)
                                       "." "pdf")))
                     (cmd (concat "convert -density 96 -quality 85 "
                                  pdffile " " imgfile)))
                (when (and (file-readable-p pdffile)
                           (file-newer-than-file-p pdffile imgfile))
                  ;; This block is executed only if pdffile is newer than
                  ;; imgfile or if imgfile does not exist.
                  (shell-command cmd)
                  (message "%s" cmd)))))))
    (user-error "`convert' executable (part of Imagemagick) is not found")))
```

## Hook setup to specify when to run this function

```el
(defun my/org-include-img-from-pdf-before-save ()
  "Execute `org-include-img-from-pdf' just before saving the file."
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook #'org-include-img-from-pdf nil :local))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'my/org-include-img-from-pdf-before-save)

;; If you want to attempt to auto-convert PDF to PNG  only during exports, and not during each save.
;; (with-eval-after-load 'ox
;;   (add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'org-include-img-from-pdf))
```

---

[Code + MWE](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/tree/master/elisp/org-include-img-from-pdf)

Comment: Does this mean that an exported file uses the png instead of the pdf?

Answer (score 3):

There is now a package on melpa just for this purpose: **org-inline-pdf**.

It is developed at github, where you also find usage information.
https://github.com/shg/org-inline-pdf.el

Note that this package needs the [pdf2svg](https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg) tool.  Also orgmode 9.4 is a minimum requirement.